# How do I enable syntax highlighting for global.asa in Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition?

Tags: asp-classic, visual-studio-2022

I have a classic ASP web application to maintain. In previous versions of Visual Studio Community, at least up until 2017 (I never used 2019), syntax highlighting worked in all files on this application. A while back, I upgraded to VS 2022, and today I had occasion to open the `global.asa` file in that application to change a DB connection string. None of the syntax (VBScript) is colorized. Only the `<script>` tags at the beginning and end of the file are colorized. In all of the `.asp` files syntax highlighting works perfectly. I've searched on Google and can find no answers to this question. Is it just not recognizing the `.asa` file extension? And if so, how do I get it to recognize that extension?

Comment: I haven't found anything on this. I did find a Microsoft page that's about this file in general, and it hasn't been updated since 2017. It's very possible support for it just isn't present anymore

Comment: Use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with the [Classic ASP Syntaxes and Snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jtjoo.classic-asp-html) installed. In my opinion this is a far better IDE for Classic ASP development.

Comment: @user692942 Yes, I like the VS Code IDE a lot. Are you using FTP to connect to the Classic ASP site(s)? I have looked at several of the FTP extensions, but the one feature they all lack that regular VS has is the ability to tell you if a file was modified since you retrieved it before saving.

Comment: @CB_Ron No, I use Git to checkout my repo and use IIS to test the site locally.